# Is learning Sifrei Neviim a fulfillment of the mitzvah to listen to a Navi?

Tags: torah-study, nevua-prophecy, navi-prophets

[There's a Torah commandment to listen to a navi.](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.516)  As far as I know, there are no neviim around nowadays to listen to, but we do have books written by the neviim.

If you learn Navi and do your best to live up to the lessons the navi meant to teach, is that a fulfillment of this mitzvah deoraisa?

(I'm not asking whether it's Talmud Torah or whether it's a good thing to do, because it's clearly both.)

Comment: As I understand it, the words of the prophets are written on the subway walls and tenement halls ... Not really ;-) I think their words were addressed to the populace of that time. Not that what they suggested to do aren't usually eternal mitzvoth and behaviors that should always be practiced. But, I don't infer anything said outside that that isn't a warning (usually) to the people of that era. In short, it seems that by reading what they said seems like not more than reading a historical narrative.

Comment: @DanF https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.224.3

Comment: Almost all of the Torah's commandments were relayed by Moshe who also was a prophet. I'm unaware of any source that says that performing Torah written mitzvoth is a fulfillment of listening to a prophet. Logically, then, do we see any mitzvah relayed by any later prophets that were **not** in the Torah? My point is - if you assume the answer being 'yes' that you are getting the mitzvah for listening to Moshe, himself a prophet, then do you also get the mitzvah of listening to all the other prophets who are just relaying what Moshe said?

Comment: I'm missing the point you are trying to emphasize in the sefaria link.

Comment: @DanF The last piece - "Any prophecy that was needed for later generations was written down, and any prophecy that wasn't needed for later generations wasn't written down."  The point is that the prophecies we have aren't just for that time, they're needed forever.